# Drawing rectangles by treating canvas as a View

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, drawrect, rectangles

Is there an easy way to draw rectangles on a canvas and display it in an activity like a TextView?

I tried to draw my rectangle like this:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA); 
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

Rect locationrect = new Rect(10, 10, 200, 100);
c.drawRect(locationrect, paint);

View locationpic = (View)findViewById(R.id.locationview);
locationpic.draw(c);
```

in my xml:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/locationview"
    android:layout_width="520dp"
    android:layout_height="489dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dp" />
```

This is apparently not working (it doesn't crash but rectangle is not displayed).. any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You will have to create custom views  extending View to use them in xml layout

Comment: I editted my post, could you check? :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a Java file and write this:

package com.samplecanvas;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

```
      public class SampleCanvasActivity extends View {
         vPaint paint = new Paint();

          public SampleCanvasActivity(Context context) {
              super(context);
           }

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(130, 130, 180, 180, paint);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    canvas.drawRect(133, 160, 177, 177, paint );
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawRect(133, 133, 177, 160, paint );

}
```

}

Use this file in ur xml

Like this.

```
  <com.samplecanvas.SampleCanvasActivity
android:id="@+id/widthView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
 />
```

Comment: I will definitely try this! But before I do, could you explain why my code is not working (I edited my post)?